# PowerBI - refresh from SQL Job (SSIS, PowerShell, C#?)

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powerbi

I need to figure out how to schedule refresh of PowerBI model just after SSIS packages (which loads data into underlying database) are completed successfully.

I **cannot** provide the script with credentials of an account which would refresh the PowerBI model published in workspace.

The SSIS packages are run in the context of Proxy account which credentials are already created in SQL Server instance.

I am wondering if there is a smart way to execute PowerBI refresh from as very last step of SSIS packages?

Other option would be to execute PowerShell script, but if I do it as SQL job step - the context of that script would be SQL Server Agent account (correct me if I am wrong). So I would have to either use the credentials in that PowerShell script (which I **cannot** do of course) or somehow read them from Proxy account?

Comment: Use Flow to trigger refresh after the job has been

Comment: can you, please give me some more details?

Comment: MS Flow has built in trigger for two SQL Server events: row insert or row modify. You can have your SSIS package insert or modify a row in a status table upon completion. This then would act as a trigger for your flow, which in turn would refresh datasets (for which there is a built-in action).

Comment: One more comment - SQL Server requires premium Flow subscription. As an alternative, you could use some other triggers, like sharepoint lists, which could be updated after job has completed. Have a look at the list of non-premium triggers, maybe that will give you some ideas.